# Why serialization object to JSON with type info works wrong?

Tags: c#, types, json.net

I works on the saving system of my game and ran into a problem:

When I deserialize JSON, types of objects in dynamic array just disappear (I use Newtonsoft.Json).

Here is how I'm make a save file:

```
SaveFile SF = new SaveFile(_Map, _Character);
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SF, new JsonSerializerSettings() {
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
});
Properties.Settings.Default._Save = json;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Loading it:

```
string saveSTR = Properties.Settings.Default._Save; 
SaveFile save = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SaveFile>(saveSTR);
if (!saveSTR.Equals(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new SaveFile(_Map, _Character), new JsonSerializerSettings() {TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All}))) {
    MessageBoxResult res = MessageBox.Show("Не сохранённый прогресс будет утерян, вы уверены что хотите продолжить?", "", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.None, MessageBoxResult.No);
    if (res == MessageBoxResult.Yes) NavigationService.Navigate(new Game(save._Character, save._Map));
    return;
}
NavigationService.Navigate(new Game(save._Character, save._Map));
```

And here is classes:

```
public class SaveFile {
    public Character _Character;
    public Map _Map;
    public SaveFile(Map _Map, Character _Character) {
        this._Map = _Map;
        this._Character = _Character;
    }
}

public class Room {
    public dynamic[,] Content;
    //...
}

public class Map {
    public Room[,] Rooms;
    //...
}
```

In JSON types exist:

[image: In JSON types exist]

But not when it deserialized:

[image: But not when it deserialized]

Can it happens because of Room.Content type is dynamic? How can I fix it?

[Here is my project.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PJE9voJeu0JFvkpFux8PoSIPXI1bLxb3) Saving into the Game.xaml.cs, classes into MainWindow.xaml.cs

Comment: TypeNameHandling.Auto?  https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm

Comment: I tried it and got same problem

Comment: Alright.  Read that page in detail and report back.

Comment: And yes, it could be because you're using a dynamic.  Try casting it to a concrete type.

Comment: So, I added TypeNameHandling.Auto in deserialize parameters, but got new error - "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException"; Type specified in JSON 'System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not compatible with 'System.IntPtr, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Path '_Map.Rooms.$values[1][2].Content.$values[3][6].Interact.Method.$type', line 1, position 3854.   For some reason, Newtonsoft cannot deserialize a function.

Comment: That's a good clue.  And yes, you're right; you can't deserialize functions.  Why would you want to?

Comment: There are structures in the rooms with which you can interact. So Structure class have a field: public Func<Map, Game, bool> Interact; that I define in Object.cs: _Structures["DДверь"].Interact = Structure_Interact4;

Comment: You'll have to extract that out into its own property.  Newtonsoft.JSON doesn't reach into Funcs.

Comment: Oh that's sad. Ok, I think I know how to implement it differently. Thanks you so much!

Comment: Serialization and deserialization are all about persisting the state of an object.  Return values from functions are not generally considered part of that state.